# sizeof() And Template Argument In ctor / Non-ctor Function

Tags: c++, constructor, templates, sizeof, arguments

I hit a snag today... I wanted to define a small templated helper class:

```
template<class T>
CMyClass
{
public : 
    CMyClass() { size_t iSize = sizeof(T); } // Allowed. 
    size_t GetElementSize() const { return sizeof(T); } // C2027.
};
```

and of course, it wouldn't compile (C2027). My question was, is it possible to get the size of the type? The reason I need this is that the type the object is constructed with could be a number of differently-defined structures, and so I need to get the size of the structure used, at run time.

Through a quick bit of experimentation, because I'm stubborn, it seems that I *can* use sizeof(T) in the ctor, but not in the non-ctor function - so my question now is... why?!

Comment: Did you really try compiling this very code? It is missing a `class` or `struct` between `template< class T >` and `CMyClass`. If you add `class`, gcc will compile just fine.

Comment: Also, try "std::size_t". The code in the constructor may seem to work, but it's not usually compiled until the constructor is instantiated when creating an object of `CMyClass<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine here, what's the message of C2027? And what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS2005, patched - I believe that is named VC8 or VC8.1?

The full error text is: 

myclass.h(170) : error C2027: use of undefined type 'T'
see declaration of 'T'
while compiling class template member function 'size_t CMyClass<T>::GetElementSize(void) const'
with
[
T=T
]
see reference to class template instantiation CMyClass<T>' being compiled
with
[
T=T
]

and it was being instantiated with

 CMyClass<SOME_STRUCT_DEF> ElementStore ; 

where SOME_STRUCT_DEF contains three floats and a DWORD + its own ctor.

Comment: Actually, I must withdraw thw question. It doesn't seem to happen in all cases - particularly, when I try to extract the bare bones and create a compilable test sample, it's not happening. Grrr!

Answer (score 2):

It can have different reasons. Consider this code:

```
// file foo.h
class X;

template<class T>
class CMyClass
{
public : 
    CMyClass() { size_t iSize = sizeof(T); } // Allowed. 
    size_t GetElementSize() const { return sizeof(T); } // C2027.
};

struct Class {
  Class(); // definition of it in the cpp file, where "X" is fully defined
  void callit() { cm.GetElementSize(); } // instantiated here!
  CMyClass<X> cm;
};
```

At the time the constructor is instantiated (in the ".cpp" file), `T` is a completely defined type. But at the time `GetElementSize` is instantiated (in the ".h" file), `X` is not yet completely defined.

Comment: @litb: I think that error would require two-phase lookup, while "C2027" hints at VC -- which unfortunately doesn't implement this.

Comment: I'm not sure about anything with VC. That compiler is too much broken for me to assume anything about it :)

Comment: @sbi:  There's no 2-phase lookup here.  2-phase lookup is the term used to describe the lookup that takes place in the scope of the argument types, for a function call that involved dependent arguments.

Comment: @litb:  I think based on the error message in the comment to the answer by "Kim Grasman" that you've supplied the correct answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the proper answer to your question is, but it seems you can work around it by just making iSize a member and have GetElementSize() return it instead of calling sizeof again.

Comment: I did discover this in the end, although I have also found that when I try and extract the relevant code to a small example, it no longer fails.